# How to read specific characters from lines in a text file using python?

Tags: python, text, io, character

I have multiple .txt files that contain multiple lines similar to this:

```
[class1] 1:-28 9:-315 13:-354227 2:-36.247 17:-342 8:-34 14:-3825
[class2] 14:-31.8679 7:-32.3582 2:-32.4127 1:-32.7257 8:-32.9804 16:-33.2156
```

I want to know how to read the numbers before the `:`s and store them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex but here is a version without, clearer than @Thrustmaster's solution imo.

```
>>> text = "[class1] 1:-28 9:-315 13:-354227 2:-36.247 17:-342 8:-34 14:-3825"
>>> [int(x.split(':')[0]) for x in text.split()[1:]]
[1, 9, 13, 2, 17, 8, 14]
```

Comment: May be you could make it take multiple lines this way too:
`[[int(x.split(':')[0]) for x in line.split()[1:]] for line in arr]`

Comment: @Thrustmaster Yeah that would work, I was just showing a small example so the OP can extend it.

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO No problem but regex is better!

Comment: @jamylak so for each file i should do smth like f=open('path','r') text=f.readlines() and then that split function? ?

Comment: You can just iterate over each line like: `for line in open('path'):` and do the operation then. Do you want all the numbers in the same array? You can see @Thrustmaster 's solution since he has already done that

Comment: Great! Thanks again. May i bother you with further questions related to this matter? I'm very new to python and I am looking for completing a part of a project in the easyest way possible (C++ just wouldn't do :) )

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO Post it as a new question along with what you have tried, you can post a link back to here. I may or may not look at it but other people will as long as it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "[class1] 1:-28 9:-315 13:-354227 2:-36.247 17:-342 8:-34 14:-3825"
>>> map(int, re.findall(r'(\S+):\S+', text)) # You could also do map(float,...)
[1, 9, 13, 2, 17, 8, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without using RE, if you know for sure the syntax of the file remains the same, you could use this:

```
>>> arr
['[class1] 1:-28 9:-315 13:-354227 2:-36.247 17:-342 8:-34 14:-3825', '[class2] 14:-31.8679 7:-32.3582 2:-32.4127 1:-32.7257 8:-32.9804 16:-33.2156']
>>> newArr = [map(lambda y: int(y[:y.index(":")]),x.split(" ")[1:]) for x in arr]
>>> newArr
[[1, 9, 13, 2, 17, 8, 14], [14, 7, 2, 1, 8, 16]]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you have several files, may be you would do something like this (based on  @jamylak's clearer version of my solution):

```
[[[int(x.split(':')[0]) for x in line.split()[1:]] for line in open(fileName)] for fileName in fileNames]
```

where `fileNames` is the array of files you are speaking about

Comment: @thebjorn Yes, it is. Its just another approach :)

Comment: I don't know if i asked the question right. I'll be even more specific. I have 25 .txt files each containing 354 lines. Every line looks like those i posted.